# Stripe.js credit card input form invisible in Webview

Tags: android, webview, stripe.js

I was trying to test if it is possible to integrate stripe js in a website and load that site in an android `Webview` to proceed for payment. I was using this link https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples to load that in `Webview` like this:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl("https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/");
```

Everything is loading in the `Webview` except the credit card field is not there. Either it is not visible or it can not be editable. Why is that?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code to enable `Javascript` in your `Webview`:

```
WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```